# Build links with ID items

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm developing an app (PHP + CodeIgniter) that has some messages (modal messages) like:

```
"Invoice #212 generated" or "This invoice is associated with payment #685."
```

Well, that ID numbers I wanna make a link to redirect user to the respective item (invoice, payment, product, person, whatever...)

So, I thought to develop at server-side, while building messages like:

```
str="Invoice#212 generated.";
replace(str, "invoice#222", "<a href='invoice/222'>invoice #222</a>")
```

Of course, using regex or something like that.

Is this the best way?  Any suggestion?

---

Messages are generated inside actions, using global function "set_message"
And
Messages as "printed" inside header, using function "echo_message"

Comment: If it works, what's the problem?

Comment: what is generating the messages? That's where you should return your url from

Comment: None. I'm just looking for other's experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you could have something like this (rough generic example):

```
$string = 'Invoice #212 generated'; // or 'See payment #121'
$string = preg_replace('/(\w+) #(\d+)/', '<a href="/$1/$2">$0</a>', $string);
```

Pretty flexible if you don't want to change previously generated strings.